# How to debug and run protractor tests in VS2019

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, protractor, visual-studio-2019

I need to create UI automation tests with a protractor, I have successfully setuped everything from http://www.protractortest.org/#/ and can successfully run the test from the command line, but for debugging and for more comfort of coding I want to use VS2019 for both editing and run/debugging.

Everything that I found is pointing to VS code and couldn't find anything for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NPM Task runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner) plugin for that.

But before you need to add `protractor conf.js` script in the `package.json` file.